# Trazar función de DISTRIBUCIÓN weibull/normal/Posisson CONOCIENDO los parámetros correspondientes

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente duda.
Quiero representar la función de DISTRIBUCIÓN (no la de densidad) de una distribución dada para diferentes ajustes (normal, possion, weibull...) Para el ejemplo tomemos la Normal. La función de densidad y los parámetros correspondientes los obtengo sin problema con el modulo scipy. Un camino más largo sería integrando la función de densidad o directamente meter la expresión de la función de distribución normal (que buscando en google se encuentra sin problema). Pero ando buscando un método más directo ya definido en algún modulo y que me permita obtener la función de distribución introduciendo como parámetros de entrada los correspondientes de la función.
Planteo los datos.

Haciendo uso del módulo scipy obtengo los parámetros de ajuste normal de una distribución como la que adjunto en la foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De aqui obtengo los parámetros:
'loc': 0.9051901354533676, 'scale': 0.5707338712121286}

Con esto me gustaría representar la función de distribución de una manera similar y sencilla hago con la función de densidad con el siguiente codigo:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9]
plt.plot(stats.norm.pdf(x, 0.9051901354533676, 0.5707338712121286))
```

El cual me representa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar valores en el eje X es más cómodo usar `numpy.arange()` que opera de forma similar a `range()`, permitiéndote especificar un valor inicial, uno final y un *paso*, sólo que en el caso de `arange()` el paso no tiene por qué ser entero y el valor final también queda incluido en los valores resultantes.

Según esto, tu línea:

```
x=[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9]
```

puede ser sustituida por:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0, 9, 0.5)
```

La ventaja de usar `arange()` es que puedes especificar un paso más pequeño, como por ejemplo `0.1` para obtener mayor "resolución" en el eje X, y por tanto una curva más suave.

Por otro lado a la hora de hacer `plt.plot()` le has pasado un único parámetro, (los puntos resultantes de computar `stats.norm.pdf()`) que `plot()` usará para dar valores en el eje Y, pero ya que a `plot()` no le has pasado qué valores usar en el eje X, usará simplemente valores correlativos 0, 1, 2, ... etc. Tantos como elementos tenga la lista a plotear.

En tu caso la lista tenía 19 valores y por ello el eje X quedaba numerado entre 0 y 19 en tu figura. Usando un paso más pequeño de 0.1, la lista a plotear tendrá 90 valores, por lo que el eje X iría numerado desde 0 hasta 89. Entiendo que no es eso lo que quieres, sino que vaya numerado entre 0 y 9 tal como son los valores de la lista `x`.

Para esto basta que pases la lista `x` como primer parámetro a `plot()`.

El código finalmente sería éste:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, 0.9051901354533676, 0.5707338712121286))
```

Que produce la siguiente figura:

[image: Resultado]

### Ampliación

La función de distribución (integral de la de densidad) es la que se conoce en inglés por *Cumulative Density Function*, y `stats.norm` también tiene un método `.cdf()` para computarla:

```
x=np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.cdf(x, 0.9051901354533676, 0.5707338712121286))
```

[image: CDF]

Comment: Hola. No es ese el problema. HE representado esa función (función de densidad) para enseñar como de una  manera sencilla se representa (con stats.norm.pdf(x, 0.9051901354533676, 0.5707338712121286)). Pero lo que realmente quiero no es la función de densidad si no la FUNCIÓN DE DISTRIBUCIÓN. Son dos conceptos distintos. La funcion de distribucion es la integral de la funcion de densidad. Y mi pregunta es si hay algún metodo inmediato como lo hay para la funcion de densidad. Gracias!

Comment: Te refieres a la cdf? He ampliado la respuesta para mostrarla

Comment: Millones de gracias! Es justo eso :)

Comment: Y sabrías cambiar la escala del eje horizontal a una logarítmica? para "estirar" y transformar la curva en una recta

Comment: Puedes usar ejes logarítmicos con `plt.xscale("log")`o `plt.yscale("log")`, pero no sé por qué esperas que va a salirte una recta. Para eso la función tendría que ser una exponencial, y realmente no se parece en nada a una.

Comment: Gracias. Investigaré a ver si encuentro lo que busco.

Comment: Para el gráfico de la funcion de distribucion (el de la Ampliacion), sabrías trasponerlo? Alternar los ejes x e y y girar la gráfca?

Comment: te refieres a lo que sale con `plt.plot(stats.norm.cdf(x, 0.9051901354533676, 0.5707338712121286), x)` ?

Comment: Si. Me gustaría que ese gráfico tuviese la altura de ola (eje que va de 0 a 8) en el eje vertical y la probabilidad (eje que va de 0 a 1 en el horizontal)

Comment: Sí, en el comentario te sugería intercambiar los parámetros `x` y `stats.norm` en el plot, no sé si te fijaste. Así sale "girado"

Comment: Cierto. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola de Nuevo. Una pregunta, y si la escala logaritmica que quiero aplicarle al eje x es por ejemplo el doble logaritmo de 1/(1 - x), es decir, ln(ln(1/(1 - x)) ? Gracias

Comment: Matplotlib no tiene ese tipo de escalas. Supongo que en esos casos deberías procesar tú mismo la lista de valores de x que se generó con `arange()`, usando la transformación que desees